# Unchecked checkmarks should be a bit lighter in color

Tags: feature-request

It is a bit too difficult to determine that the checkmark is checked. Using a lighter color, as with the up/down vote arrows would do the trick, I think.

As is, some newcomers will have some difficulty in determining the purpose of the checkmark button. If it used the same unchecked/unselected color as the upvote/downvote buttons, there would be no problem.

[image]

Comment: just to clarify, you're saying the checkmarks next to other answers to your question (gray) are too close in color to the selected answer's checkmark (green)?  your screencap shows an unselected checkmark.

Comment: I'm not saying they are too close in color; I am saying that the unchecked checkmarks are simply too dark. A user should be able to look at this and say, "Yes, that is unchecked. If I check it, it will change." I believe that some users will look at this currently and say, "I am not sure if that is checked". For experienced users who know the difference, it is not an issue.

Comment: The unchecked checkmark looks to be the same color as the unstarred star. I don't think it's likely that many people would be confused by it.

Comment: The unchecked checkmark is significantly darker than the un-pressed vote icons.

Comment: You're saying that newcomers may not realize that the check mark needs to be selected because it already looks "checked" (selected). You have a point, us "oldtimers" know that a selected checkmark is *green*, but it's not blindingly obvious to a newbie. Please confirm if I have interpreted your request correctly, it appears there are some users who are confused by what you mean exactly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That is correct, it is primarily newcomers that will be confused by the color of the unchecked checkmark, because it is too dark.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that there could be some improvement in the difference in color between checked and unchecked.  A slightly more greener "checked" checkmark or a slightly lighter gray "unchecked" checkmark would solve this.

But at the same time, all of the other buttons on the site that indicate "clicked or not" start out gray as well, and change into a colored version when clicked.  This by itself is a clear and consistent indication.

Here they are side by side.  Take note of the gray-to-colored indication in the voting buttons as well:
[image]

Lastly, keep in mind that *only the questioner will see any "unchecked" checkmarks*.  If there are multiple answers provided to the question, **they would all appear gray at first**, and obviously only one of them can be selected as correct.

---

Here's a crude mspaint mockup for your suggestion.  I have to say, I like it better than the darker checkmark.
[image]

Comment: All i'm suggesting is a lighter gray, just like the upvote/downvote buttons start out lighter gray when they have not been selected.

Comment: @GeorgeWBush see my edit.  i think i agree with you.

Comment: The proposed grey shade *does* look better.